# Win over a girl who is going through a break up

Tags: relationships, germany

I like a girl who is dealing with a break up since June.

We work in the same office building but in different departments. We hardly see each other at work. I am 27 and she is 26. She is a German and I am not.

We went out just a couple times for coffee and lunch before I told her how I feel. She said she wants to be single for at least a year. She had watery eyes when she told me about her former lover. The relationship lasted for 5 years. So, I believe that she is just not coming up with an excuse. Since, things are not clear, I want to wait.

I am ready to give her time and space, but how should I proceed? Text once a week or meet twice a month? I don't want her to feel that I am pressurizing her and also not completely vanish from her life. I am not good at gauging such situations, so I need a detailed course of action.

Comment: There's no perfect formula for winning over a girl, I think.

Comment: I know that :). I just don't know how often should I contact her without making her feel uncomfortable. I am very bad at this so needed a third person's view.

Comment: That‘s what people say, and she might change her mind quickly - or not. I suggest you spend time with her and make her feel comfortable and from time to time get closer - but no pressuring, of course. If she wants more - fine. If not, at least she knows you are interested. Waiting until she‘s ‚ready‘ sounds noble, in my personal experience it is less than realistic.

Comment: The comforting guy might be her new lover, old theme in literature.

Comment: When you told her how you felt, did she tell you that she liked you and she is not ready for a relationship. Has she given any indication, if not for getting over the break up, she would be willing to start a relationship with you?.

Comment: @clark No indications as such. She is said she is not thinking about guys at all. She was clear that she still has some residual feelings for her ex. So I guess, as of now, she has no space for feelings towards me or may be for anybody else.

Comment: Since this is already closed: Your best shot is to be there, and to ensure she knows you are still interested (not just as a friend), without coming across as pressuring/creepy/needy. You can do that through compliments, gentlemanly gestures, and tiny presents (e.g. a single flower no more often than once a month). Also give yourself some time limit, because if it drags on too long, chances are she'll just find a boyfriend who is not-you, and you'll be crushed.

Answer (score 5):

I would continue exactly the same. Go out for coffee with her. Be her friend. If you can wait, then take the time to get to know her better as friends. What she needs now is stability. Be that stability and friendship for her. Currently she is (effectively) grieving.

And don't expect anything. Don't expect her to rush, don't expect June to come and suddenly she's interested. This will take time. And there is no guarantee that she'll be interested at the end of it, and you need to be okay with that. If you can't be okay with that, then you need to question if you want to be friends at all.